# collision detection of two objects in different class

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am calling two different object from two different node
 in rock.h

```
@interface Rock : CCnode {

int screenWidth;
int screenHeight;
float downWardSpeed;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) CCSprite *falling_rock;

-(void) makeEnemyGoLower;
-(CGSize)contentSize_ofBugSprite;
-(CGRect)boundingBox_forRock;
end
```

In rock .m

```
-(CGRect)boundingBox_forRock
{
  return  falling_rock.boundingBox;
}

-(CGSize)contentSize_ofBugSprite
 {
 return falling_rock.contentSize;
}

-(void) runEnemyAnimationSequence:(ccTime) delta {

self.position = ccp(self.position.x, self.position.y - downWardSpeed  );

}
```

Similarly for player class also. Now i am calling then in main game class using **ccnode** but their position in **NSLOG** is not coming correct.SO i am unable to check collision.

Please help, what mistake i am making?

Comment: Can you please show how you add Rock and player in main game using CCNode?

Comment: rock = [Rock node];
    [self addChild:rock z:55];
This way

Comment: Ok, for collision detection you have to make two CGRect using respective object of classes and you have to check CGRectIntersectRect between those two CGRects.If, it gives true than there is a collision detection and if it gives false than there is no collision detection.

Comment: Yes,i did that but they were not colliding correctly.So i Nslog the CGrect position of theirs and find the position are wrongly shown.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the syntax is correct since I use cocos2d-x, but I believe the issue is that both boundingBoxes have to be in world space. You can use the convertToWorldSpace method to get your position from local space to world space.

Should look something like this:

```
-(CGRect)boundingBox_forRock
{
    CGPoint worldPosition = convertToWorldSpace(getPosition());
    return CGRectMake(worldPosition.x, worldPosition.y, getContentSize().width, getContentSize().height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to get Rock object's falling_rock property position.

instead of this :

```
-(void) runEnemyAnimationSequence:(ccTime) delta {

self.position = ccp(self.position.x, self.position.y - downWardSpeed  );

 }
```

try this:

```
-(void) runEnemyAnimationSequence:(ccTime) delta {

falling_rock.position = ccp(falling_rock.position.x, falling_rock.position.y - downWardSpeed  );

 }
```

Now in your main game class(GameController) u can get correct position.
Do something like this:
in your .h file

```
Rock *myRock;
```

and in your .m file to get sprite position

```
CGPoint rockCurrentPosition = ccp(myRock.falling_rock.position.x, myRock.falling_rock.position.y);
```